# java-reading and writing persian strings or other language rahter than english to text files

Tags: java

i want a code with any class of java.io package or other package if available,
to read and write a string like "سلام به همه دوستانم" (persian language)
from the file. but i failed to find a good way for it.
the problem is in saving to the file: it shows ? after that in a program like notepad
thank you all
here is the code i tried:

```
public static int saveInputToFile(String filelocation) throws IOException
{
    // it will save from console to file;

    // temp data
    // int buffersize = 1;
    // char[] buffer = new char[buffersize];
    //
    // create open file, save userInput(an string) into the file

    // create file:
    File file = new File(filelocation);// to position: file exist, then
                                        // opens, file not exist then
                                        // created and opens
    // read one line data
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String userInputLine = bufReader.readLine();
    //
    // write one line data to the file
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
    writer.write(userInputLine);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    // goal achieved data has been saved to file.
    return 0;

}

public static int saveInputToFileVer2(String filelocation)
        throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    // OutputStream outSTream = new FileOutputStream(filelocation);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filelocation, "UTF-8");
    //
    String data = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

    LOOP: while (true) {
        System.out.println("please enter your data to save:");
        data += scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("do you want to append other data? yes:y no:n");
        char choice = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'y') {
            continue;
        } else {// choise = 'n'
            break LOOP;
        }
    }

    writer.println(data);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("write ended successfully");
    // end
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8");` Are you sure that `System.in` is encoded using `UTF-8`?

Comment: If you are on Windows and you are running your app on console check its code page. You can use `chcp` command. For me it returns `852` so proper encoding for me is code page `cp852` when I read from `System.in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "UTF-8" from the streams and put it in the string which is going to be written in the file 
**Be aware of writing English with Arabic or Persian chars it causes some conflict sometimes**

```
   InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String userInputLine = bufReader.readLine();
    //
    // write one line data to the file
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
    writer.write(new String(userInputLine.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    writer.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

1-the trick is store in arabic and show in persian

change text from arabic to farsi

```
text.trim().replaceAll("ی", "ي").replaceAll("ک", "ك");
```

change text from farsi to arabic

```
text.trim().replaceAll("ي", "ی").replaceAll("ك","ک");
```

2-another way is store in base64 format and store it